# Can't set breakpoint in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I'm using eclipse (and also the groovy-eclipse plugin), and sometimes I can't set breakpoints on lines.  I'll double click the gutter, and the breakpoint will flash on then off, and it will set the breakpoint somewhere else, lower in the code.

I'll be able to set breakpoints fine for certain parts of the code, but some sections of the code will exhibit the above described behavior.

When this happens I have to restart eclipse, or cut the code i want to set the breakpoint on, and paste it lower in the file.

Anyone else experience this, or have an idea what causes it?

Comment: what version of the jdk are you using? I had this problem when using jdk 1.6.0_14

Comment: @lynxforest 1.6.0_22. What version are you using now that doesn't have the problem?

Comment: that's the same version I'm using, nevermind it must be a different issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Groovy-Eclipse are you using?  We have recently fixed a few problems in this area.  I'd recommend updating to the latest release, 2.1.1.

There is one known open issue in this area, documented here:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-888

There may be more issues and if you find any strange breakpoint setting behavior after updating, then please raise a new jira issue for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are few types of breakpoints available in Eclipse:

1. Line Breakpoint -> Lines those will be executing. You will always get a breakpoint.
2. Method Breakpoint -> for methods
3. WatchPoint -> for member declarations.
4. BreakPoint -> for class level breakpoint

When u double click for breakpoint at a line containing bracket "{" or "}", the LineBreakPoint is set to the next executable line automatically.